# Determine if two polyhedrals are the same shape and if so, map their vertices

Tags: combinatorics, computational-geometry, polyhedra

I have a polyhedron and want to determine whether it is combinatorially equivalent to another polyhedron. I know how many faces comprise each polyhedron and for each face, I know all of its vertices, and for each vertex, I know its location.

For example, if I had a pentahedron, I would want to figure out whether it was a triangular prism or a square pyramid. I can easily do this for pentahedral, but do not know how to do it for arbitrary polyhedra.

Additionally, if two polyhedra are the the same shape, I want to map the vertices from one to the other.

Can anyone point me to an algorithm to accomplish these things?

Comment: So is this like the polyhedron version of [graph isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.D. has pointed out in a comment, this is [a special case of the graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Solved_special_cases). No polynomial-time algorithm is known for the general case, but there are special-purpose algorithms for [planar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), [polyhedral graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph) (graphs of convex polyhedra) and graphs of general polyhedra. The introduction to [this paper](http://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.190/Mitarbeiter/wagner/P3C-GI_ECCC_Submission.pdf) contains a useful collection of references, including one to [this paper](http://cs.brown.edu/sites/jgaa/accepted/2004/KuklukHolderCook2004.8.3.pdf), which takes a practical point of view and finds that the linear-time algorithm for planar graphs is only more efficient than state-of-the-art general-purpose graph isomorphism algorithms if there are about $1000$ vertices or more. This is typical for the graph isomorphism problem, which is quite easy to solve in most cases but has peculiar theoretical properties.

Comment: Thanks! That was a key understanding I was missing, and it helped me look the right places for the rest of what I'm looking for.